# How to do proper error handling in services

Tags: symfony, error-handling, symfony4

I am writing a small service for a Symfony 4 project
and I'm just wondering if my error handling is a good idea.
My class currently looks like this:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\;

/**
 * Class XMLHelper
 * @package App\Service
 */
class XMLHelper
{

    public function getContent(string $path): array
    {
        $fileSystem = new Filesystem();
        if ($fileSystem->exists($path)) {

            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
            $object = simplexml_load_file($path);

            if ($object === false) {
                $str = 'Failed loading XML: ';
                foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                    $str = $error->message . ', ';
                }
                throw new \UnexpectedValueException($str);
            }

            return $object;

        } else {
            throw new \FileNotFoundException('File ' . $path . ' not found.');
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, do I need that at all? Will symfony not throw 
out an error anyway. Is the output not superfluous? How do 
you do it the best or generally correctly? If you have own 
Exceptions in Services.

Comment: So, you enable ``libxml_use_internal_errors`` just to throw the errors again yourself? What do you wish to achieve by this?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should never hesitate to throw an exception when appropriate. Your code looks just fine, it provides an exhaustive information about the encountered exeptions.

There is nothing to do with Symfony ifself, it up to your code to throw right exceptions in right places.

Hope this helps.

P.S. And don't forget to `libxml_clear_errors();`